# Converting base64 to Blob and Blob to base64 using FileReader in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, blob, phantomjs, karma-runner, filereader

I have angular controller, which should work with images. It have a watcher for property `file` in scope. If property will contain array of files, these files (only first file) should be read by `FileReader` and converted to base64 string and added to page. Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('file', function (files) {
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
        if (files[0].type && files[0].type.match('image.*')) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                render(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

and `render` function:

```
function render (src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (image.width < MIN_SIZE || image.height < MIN_SIZE) {
            $scope.error = $filter('localize')('UploaderWindow_ImageSizeError');
            $scope.$apply();
        } else {
            new global.ICropper('original-image', {
                gap: 0,
                keepSquare: true,
                image: src,
                preview: ['cropped-image']
            });
        }
    });
    image.addEventListener('error', function () {
        $scope.error = $filter('localize')('UploaderWindow_SelectImage');
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    image.src = src;
};
```

ICropper should create `img` element in DOM with base64 in `src` attribute.
The problem is, I have unit test for this functionality. Test case:

```
it('Should render new image from file input', function () {
    var imageData = image.split(',')[1],
        imageType = image.split(',')[0].replace('data:', '').replace(';base64', ''),
        file = base64toBlob(imageData, imageType);

    expect(originalImage.lastElementChild).toBe(null);
    runs(function () {
        $scope.file = [file];
        $scope.$apply();
    });
    waitsFor(function () {
        return originalImage.lastElementChild;
    }, 'waiting_original_form');
    runs(function () {
        expect(originalImage.lastElementChild.src).toBe(image);
    });
});
```

Variable `image` contains valid base64 string, `originalImage.lastElementChild` - img element, which should be created by ICropper. The body of `base64toBlob` function:

```
function base64toBlob (b64Data, contentType) {
    var binary = atob(b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '')),
        binaryLength = binary.length,
        buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryLength),
        view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLength; i++) {
        view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([view], {type: contentType});
}
```

This test successfully passed in Chrome, but not in PhantomJS:

```
timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for waiting_original_form
```

I think, it's because load event for image not fired, error fired instead. But I don't understand why? I know, that `Blob` not defined in PhantomJS, so I use this polyfill: https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js

Comment: Maybe the problem is unsupported FileReader. But I can't find some polyfills for FileReader for PhantomJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load file into IMAGE object using Phantom.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978246/load-file-into-image-object-using-phantom-js)